# Function Prototypes interfering with compiler seeing the definition?

Tags: c++, function, prototype, void

I'm trying to write code for a "Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock" game as part of a lab for my class. In other programs I've used function prototypes with some success, but when I'm doing it here it doesn't work. The compiler reads the void functions if I place them above main, but I need them to be defined after. I tried initializing them like this

```
#include <iostream> // basic i/o
#include <iomanip> // output formatting
#include <cmath> // math functions
#include <cstdlib> // rand() and srand()
#include <ctime> // system time
#include <string> // string handling

using namespace std;


void playerRock();
void playerPaper();
void playerScissors();
void playerLizard();
void playerSpock();



int main(){...
```

which hasn't cause me any issues in other programs, and I've seen both my prof and my textbook do this exact thing, but my compiler doesn't seem to recognize the following as function definitions and I'm not sure why

```
int main(){...
}

void playerRock(void){
    cout << "Player chooses Rock" << endl;
    if(opponentChoice == 1){
        cout << "Opponent chooses Paper" << endl;
        cout << "Paper covers Rock!" << endl;
        opponentScore++;
    }
    if(opponentChoice == 2){
        cout << "Opponent chooses Scissors" << endl;
        cout << "Rock smashes Scissors!" << endl;
        playerScore++;
    }
    if(opponentChoice == 3){
        cout << "Opponent chooses Lizard" << endl;
        cout << "Rock smashes Lizard" << endl;
        playerScore++;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Opponent chooses Spock" << endl;
        cout << "Spock vaporizes Rock!" << endl;
        opponentScore++;
    }
    cout << "Opponent Score: " << opponentScore << endl;
    cout << "Player Score: " << playerScore << endl;

    return;
}

void playerPaper(void){
    cout << "Player chooses Paper!" << endl;
    if(opponentChoice == 0){
        cout << "Opponent chooses Rock" << endl;
        cout << "Paper covers Rock!" << endl;
        playerScore++;
    }
    if(opponentChoice == 2){
        cout << "Opponent chooses Scissors" << endl;
        cout << "Scissors cuts Paper!" << endl;
        opponentScore++;
    }
    if(opponentScore == 3){
        cout << "Opponent chooses Lizard" << endl;
        cout << "Lizard eats Paper!" << endl;
        opponentScore++;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Opponent chooses Spock" << endl;
        cout << "Paper disproves Spock!" << endl;
        playerScore++;
    }
    cout << "Opponent Score: " << opponentScore << endl;
    cout << "Player Score: " << playerScore << endl;

    return;
}

void playerScissors(void){
    cout << "Player chooses Scissors" << endl;
    if(opponentChoice == 0){
        cout << "Opponent chooses Rock" << endl;
        cout << "Rock smashes Scissors" << endl;
        opponentScore++;
    }
    if(opponentChoice == 1){
        cout << "Opponent chooses Paper" << endl;
        cout << "Scissors cuts Paper!" << endl;
        playerScore++;
    }
    if(opponentChoice == 3){
        cout << "Opponent chooses Lizard" << endl;
        cout << "Scissors decapitate Lizard!" << endl;
        playerScore++;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Opponent chooses Spock" << endl;
        cout << "Spock smashes Scissors!" << endl;
        opponentScore++;
    }
    cout << "Opponent Score: " << opponentScore << endl;
    cout << "Player Score: " << playerScore << endl;

    return;

}

void playerLizard(void){
    cout << "Player chooses Lizard" << endl;
    if(opponentChoice == 0){
        cout << "Opponent chooses Rock" << endl;
        cout << "Rock smashes Lizard" << endl;
        opponentScore++;
    }
    if(opponentChoice == 1){
        cout << "Opponent chooses Paper" << endl;
        cout << "Lizard eats Paper!" << endl;
        playerScore++;
    }
    if(opponentChoice == 2){
        cout << "Opponent chooses Scissors" << endl;
        cout << "Scissors decapitates Lizard" << endl;
        opponentScore++;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Opponent chooses Spock" << endl;
        cout << "Lizard poisons Spock!" << endl;
        playerScore++;
    }
    cout << "Opponent Score: " << opponentScore << endl;
    cout << "Player Score: " << playerScore << endl;

    return;
}

void playerSpock(void){
    cout << "Player chooses Spock" << endl;
    if(opponentChoice == 0){
        cout << "Opponent chooses Rock" << endl;
        cout << "Spock vaporizes Rock!" << endl;
        playerScore++;
    }
    if(opponentChoice == 1){
        cout << "Opponent chooses Paper" << endl;
        cout << "Paper disproves Spock" << endl;
        opponentScore++;
    }
    if(opponentChoice == 2){
        cout << "Opponent chooses Scissors" << endl;
        cout << "Spock breaks Scissors!" << endl;
        playerScore++;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Opponent chooses Lizard" << endl;
        cout << "Lizard poisons Spock!" << endl;
        opponentScore++;
    }
    cout << "Opponent Score: " << opponentScore << endl;
    cout << "Player Score: " << playerScore << endl;

    return;
}
```

I guess I'm confused as to why this would work in other programs but not here?

Comment: What makes you think the compiler is not recognising those function definitions?    If it is reporting errors, what are they saying?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this probably has more to do with variable scope, but can you please give us the specific errors that your compiler is generating?

Comment: The function declaration should be present before you call it in the main function. So, that part is correct. We would better understand the issue if you also post the compiler errors.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm still new to all this.

when I attempt to compile it its returning this error:

            error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
            void playerRock(void){

Answer (score 0):

A function's *declaration* must be visible at the point of its usage. If you call `playerRock` in `main`, then you must have at least a *declaration* of `playerRock` before `main`. You can *define* (write the actual body of the function) it in some other place, after `main` for example, like you did.

```
void playerRock();
```

This is a *declaration* of `playerRock`.

```
void playerRock() {
 // something
}
```

This is a *definition* of `playerRock`.

Also note that you don't need the `void` in function parameter list in c++.